# Wordpress ACF Repeater background image only loading last image

Tags: css, wordpress, background, advanced-custom-fields, slick.js

I have a slick carousel and I want the dots to dynamically display the image on the slide that is being displayed currently.

The image is coming dynamically through a Wordpress ACF Repeater, that I've placed in the head

Here's What the code in my head looks like:

```
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <style type="text/css">
  <?php if( have_rows('testimonial_slides') ): ?>

    .testimonial_slider_dots li {
        background: #FFF0CE;
        height: 10px;
        width: 10px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        margin: 15% 0;
    }

    .testimonial_slider_dots .slick-active {
        <?php while( have_rows('testimonial_slides') ): the_row();
            $icon = get_sub_field('testimonials_slide_product_icon');
        ?> 
            background: url('<?php echo $icon['url']; ?>');
        <?php endwhile; ?>
        background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
        background-position: 50% 50% !important;
        background-size: cover !important;
        width: 50px !important;
        height: 50px !important;
    }

  <?php endif; ?>
  </style>
  @php wp_head() @endphp
</head>
```

Here's my JS

```
$('.testimonials-slider').slick({
    dots: true,
    arrows: false,
    infinite: true,
    //autoplay: true,
    slidesToShow: 1,
    adaptiveHeight: true,
    dotsClass: 'testimonial_slider_dots',
    responsive: [
        {   
            breakpoint: 768,
            adaptiveHeight: false,
        },
    ],
});
```

The image is displaying, but I'm only seeing the last image in the repeater, and not the specific image that matches the slide I'm currently seeing.

EDIT:

Here's the HTML:

```
<ul class="testimonial_slider_dots" style="display: flex;" role="tablist">
    <li class="slick-active" role="presentation">
        <button type="button" role="tab" id="slick-slide-control10" aria-controls="slick-slide10" aria-label="1 of 6" tabindex="0" aria-selected="true">1</button>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation">
        <button type="button" role="tab" id="slick-slide-control11" aria-controls="slick-slide11" aria-label="2 of 6" tabindex="-1">2</button>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation">
        <button type="button" role="tab" id="slick-slide-control12" aria-controls="slick-slide12" aria-label="3 of 6" tabindex="-1">3</button>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation">
        <button type="button" role="tab" id="slick-slide-control13" aria-controls="slick-slide13" aria-label="4 of 6" tabindex="-1">4</button>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation">
        <button type="button" role="tab" id="slick-slide-control14" aria-controls="slick-slide14" aria-label="5 of 6" tabindex="-1">5</button>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation"><button type="button" role="tab" id="slick-slide-control15" aria-controls="slick-slide15" aria-label="6 of 6" tabindex="-1">6</button>
    </li>
</ul>
```

When the page loads, here's what the css looks like on inspect:

[screenshot of css on load](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h0QT2.png)

Comment: Could you please share the HTML that you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

What's happening is that each time you instantiate a new background image in the inline-block css it overrides the next one. I would suggest writing inline background image on the element for each slide, this will stop the css from overwriting each other.

So your dynamic code will look something like this

```
<div class="testimonial-slider">
   <?php while( have_rows('testimonial_slides') ): the_row(); ?>
      <div class="single-slide" style="background-image: <?php get_sub_field('testimonials_slide_product_icon')['url']; ?>">
  <?php endwhile; ?>
</div>
```